# Mathematical game - finding values

Tags: probability

I have a small mathematical game. A random number with uniform distribution between 1 and 10 is drawn, the player must guess any number except the the one drawn.The method I have found is by selecting the same number for every draw, the player will win 9 times out of 10. My question is , is there a better method of playing,lets say the player wins 29 times out of 30, that is a ratio of 9.66 out of 10?

Comment: No. Except by picking $11$ maybe

Comment: @free man: i also have the same question.

Comment: There is no bad strategy either.

Comment: Is the random number an integer from 1 to 10 or a real number?

Comment: It's an integer

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy might depend on the lack of 'randomness' of you random numbers source, if any.

For a truly random source, if there is no history-dependence which would cause a correlation between consecutive outputs, you have no better and no worse strategy than guessing $1$ every time. However if the source isn't ideal (say, it returns numbers in a cycle: $1,\,2,\,3,\dots,\,10,\,1,\,2,\dots$) you might discover it and adjust the strategy accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the chosen number has to also be on the same range, there's no strategy better or worse than picking the same number every time. Whichever number your strategy tells you to pick is selected by the random process exactly $\frac{1}{10}$ of the time because the distribution is uniform.